# While and try-catch stracture and exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I want to get an input from user continually but with some restrictions. Input must contain 1 integer, 1 string, 1 integer, 1 string. (i.e. "3+1-", "1a4k"). If the user give input in a wrong way, I will warn like "Bad input".

```
int a = scanner.nextInt();
String b = scanner.next();
int c = scanner.nextInt();
String d = scanner.next();
```

I will use that stracture to obtain input what I want. However, if user do not enter an integer value for a, user enter other value like String or something else, I also want to warn like "Bad input". I could not handle it. I simply coded like that:

```
while(true) {
     try {
         System.out.print("Enter: ");
         int a = scanner.nextInt();
         String b = scanner.next();
         int c = scanner.nextInt();
         String d = scanner.next();
         // Some logics
     } 
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Bad input");
         scanner.next();
     }
}
```

"3 + 1 -", "2 a 2 e", "3 t 3 -" is OK.

"3+ 1 -", "3 + 1-", "3+ 1-", "3+1-" is not OK.

I'm good with OKs, there is no problem. However, more than one warning has been output when inputs are not OK. I just want one warning.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consume the end of the current line in both the case where an exception occurs and the case where the input is OK, but you want the next iteration of the loop to read input from the next line.

```
while(true) {
     try {
         System.out.print("Enter: ");
         int a = scanner.nextInt();
         String b = scanner.next();
         int c = scanner.nextInt();
         String d = scanner.next();
         scanner.nextLine();
         // Some logics
     } 
     catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Bad input");
         scanner.nextLine();
     }
}
```